# How can I make sure my data is sanitised before and after firebase login?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**SITUATION:**

I am trying to sanitise the data the user inputs when logging in.

Sanitisation should be done server side but a Firebase login must be done on the client.

My idea is the following: make an ajax request to sanitise the data, then login with sanitized data.

Then make a second ajax request to write certain login information to the database (this is necessary but not directly related to the login itself, must be done just after login though).

---

**PROBLEM:**

The issue I have is the following:

I asked on the security stack exchange and they told me that the first ajax request was basically useless since it could easily be bypassed.

Meaning a user could input unsanitised data and that data would be passed to the email and password fields of the login Firebase function.

I could move the sanitisation code to the second ajax request and delete the first one so that all the data I write to the database is sanitised but I don't know what to do for the login function fields.

Also, the first ajax request checks the recaptcha.

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I make sure all data is sanitised and the recaptcha is correctly verified in a way that does not allow to bypass that check ?

```
   $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var email = $("#loginEmail").val();
    var password = $("#loginPassword").val();

    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login",
        data: $this.serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {

        console.log("GO!");

        if (data) {

            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password ).then( authData => {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login2",
                    data: authData
                }).done(function(result) {
                    if (result == "SUCCESS0!") {
                        localStorage.setItem('amazingProMembership',true);
                        localStorage.setItem('success_msg_local2', 'You have logged in');
                        window.location.href="/screenshots/index";
                    }
                    else if (result == "SUCCESS1!") {
                        localStorage.setItem('success_msg_local2', 'You have logged in');
                        window.location.href="/screenshots/index";
                    }
                    else if (result == "ERROR!"){
                        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
                            localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local', 'Please confirm your email address. Check your inbox.');
                            window.location.href="/users/login";
                            ("Login Failed: ", error);

                        });
                    }
                });

            },function(error) { 

                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local', "Unknown user or password");
                window.location.href="/users/login";
                ("Login Failed: ", errorMessage, errorCode);

            });  
        }
        else {
            localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local',  'Recaptcha failed'); window.location.href = "/users/login";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding data to Realtime Database, if you want to ensure data is correctly validated and sanitized on the server side, the easiest and most secure way to do that with [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).  You can write a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to execute whenever data is changed at a location of interest to make changes to the data if necessary.  A function can also call other APIs, including recaptcha, as needed.

Comment: Can I use them to sanitise data that is used to create a user also ? (that data is not written to the database, it's written to the auth system to my knowledge)

Comment: You can write an authentication trigger that run when a new user is created, then make further changes as necessary.  But I'd still store profile data in the database so you can access it even if you don't have a user object from Firebase Authentication.

Comment: All data including auth data is also stored in the db (except password obviously), I was just wondering how to make sure users are not created in the auth system with junk data.

Comment: One more thing I really dislike: I was expecting firebase to automatically sanitise data before they create a user, it seems so basic and obvious, I am rather surprised it's not the case 00 I really don't feel very happy about having to use another firebase product (cloud functions) that is going to cost me more money just to perform something that should be performed automatically by Firebase.